# How to Vary the wavelength of UV CFL?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, oscillators, wavelength

I have a $12$ $V$ $DC$ operated UV $[CFL]$(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_fluorescent_lamp) with $365$ $nm$ wavelength. I need to vary this wavelength in the  $250-300-350-400-450-500$ $nm$. Please guide me regarding how to proceed with it.

Comment: The wavelength of a CFL is given by the physics of the gas discharge and theres is nothing you can do from the outside to change that significantly (assuming you are not trying to abuse the tube by increasing the discharge current to increase some weak lines). You can use up- and down-converting optical dyes to change the light, but I am not aware that such dyes exist for the 250nm range. You may have some luck with the longer end of your wavelength range. The better solution, IMHO, is to get a range of tubes with the proper wavelengths if they are available.

Comment: Can't really be done **BUT** that is NOT your application. Decsribe what you are trying to achieve and people MAY be able to suggest a solution. fwiw 250 nM is "rather deep" UV and 500 nM is not really UV at all. What power do you need? Why the wavelength range? Does it need to be contoinuous or can it be at discrete points? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Either way this is a pretty engineer-y question

Answer (score 0):

Mount the lamp on the outside of a really fast spaceship.

If you want a longer wavelength, fire up the engines of the spaceship and get it to travel away from you, so that the light is red-shifted.

If you want a shorter wavelength, do the same but with the spaceship travelling towards you, so that the light is blue-shifted.